How to update system installation of python (setuptools) on Ubuntu
I get the following warning from AWS Inspector on the Ubuntu machine:

CVE-2024-6345 - setuptools, setuptools Finding ID:
arn:aws:inspector2:eu-west-1:355370908234:finding/348da83463e3a933ffccae7dcffeb1cc
A vulnerability in the package_index module of pypa/setuptools
versions up to 69.1.1 allows for remote code execution via its
download functions. These functions, which are used to download
packages from URLs provided by users or retrieved from package index
servers, are susceptible to code injection. If these functions are
exposed to user-controlled inputs, such as package URLs, they can
execute arbitrary commands on the system. The issue is fixed in
version 70.0.

As I understand I now need install version 70. My assumption is that this is related to the system wide pre-installed version of python/pip on my machine. What's the correct way to update setuptools for the system wide python installation on Ubuntu?
Running this:
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade setuptools

gives well known error externally-managed-environment:

error: externally-managed-environment
× This environment is externally managed ╰─> To install Python
packages system-wide, try apt install
python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
install...
See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python
installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at
the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing
--break-system-packages. hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

This command:
$ sudo apt install python3-setuptools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-setuptools is already the newest version (68.1.2-2ubuntu1.1).
python3-setuptools set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

doesn't install v70, it says 68 is the most recent one. However, pypi specifies the latest version of setuptools is 75, I'm wondering why apt package falls so far behind?
I could probably go with the option of using --break-system-packages to install setuptools directly through pip instead of using apt, but I'd like to avoid that

Debian/Ubuntu backport security fixes to their packaged versions, but they don't update them otherwise to avoid potential breaking changes.
The changelog for python-setuptools_69.1.2-2ubuntu1.1 says the fix for your issue is already included.
   * SECURITY UPDATE: remote code execution via package download functions
     - debian/patches/CVE-2024-6345.patch: modernize and fix VCS handling
       to prevent code injection in setuptools/package_index.py and
       setuptools/tests/test_packageindex.py. Also update setup.cfg to
       include new test dependencies.
     - CVE-2024-6345

You can see the changelog at /usr/share/doc/python3-setuptools/changelog.Debian.gz or via the "View changes file" link on the package's Launchpad page.

thanks, so how can I use this fix?

According to the apt output you posted this update has already been installed on your system so you're good to go. Usually the people who find bugs like this give OS vendors a warning about this a few weeks before the public announcement, so they have a chance to get a fix ready.

but the apt gives me version 68.1.2-2ubuntu1.1, not 69.1.2-2ubuntu1.1 
